# Did anyone back in America know about Michael's marriage to Appolonia in Sicily?

Tags: the-godfather-2, the-godfather

During the course of [*The Godfather*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/) Michael marries Appolonia in Sicily. A failed assasination attempt results in her death. Shortly after, Michael returns to New York and marries Kay Adams. There was no mention of Appolonia in the rest of the Godfather trilogy apart from a deleted scene where her killer was murdered by a car bomb and a flashback at the end of 3. Did anyone back in America know of the marriage?

Comment: Great question , just like how micheal didnt really say anything when told of sonnys death , or did connie know about Fredos real death as opposed to "drowning" even though he would have a bullet wound in his 'ed

Comment: @howler I don't think *Connie* knows about *Fredo*'s real death, as she still speaks of drowning in *Part 3* and it doesn't make so much sense for her to just pretend that. Though, *Kay* knows it very well and says that *Anthony* does also, while *Mary* doesn't seem to know it. It seems to be a family secret half the people knew and didn't tell the other half to not hurt them or *Michael*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the film, this was never revealed. In the book, Kay is told by Michael Corleone's mother to forget about him, implying that Corleone was already married and would never return to the US. The family in the novel The Godfather is well aware of Michael's actions in Sicily.

Since the film leaves out Michael Corleone's revenge against the man who planted the bomb in the car which killed Apollonia it is clear that her death closes that thread of the tale.

Comment: There is a deleted scene from the first movie where Michael is seen post-explosion and recovering from his wounds. He orders a hit on Appolonia's killers. So his family back in America would probably have heard of it.

Comment: The only problem with that is that he had no idea where the man was. In the novel, the man has relocated to the US and is working in in a pizza parlor in the Buffalo,NY area. One of the Corleone button men (assassins) walks into the parlor, identifies the man by a tattoo which he was known to have had and then shoots and kills him.

Comment: @SystemDown Mistah Mix: IMO, both your comments are suitable answers.

Comment: pretty sure i saw the bomb planter killed at some point, possibly during the 'day of  reckoning'.

Answer (score 4):

In The Godfather 3, a wise and aged Michael Corleone shows a photo of Apollonia to his daughter Mary and his son Anthony saying

> She was wonderful, beautiful. I loved her. And then she died. My
>   trusted bodyguard planted a bomb in my car. She drove it before I did.

The idea behind this conversation was to convince Mary to stop her relationship with Vincent Mancini, the illegitimate son of Sonny Corleone and Lucy Mancini.

> When they come... they come at what you love.

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help). While this is certainly interesting to know, it doesn't address the actual question that much (or you might want to clarify in which way it does).

Answer (score 0):

Kay knew.  In the book, she sort of put the pieces together.  Also, in Part 3, she sarcastically mentions the marriage when Michael tells her he never stopped thinking about her in Sicily.